# remove files from subfolders without the last three

Tags: bash, shell, nested-loops

I have a structure like that:

```
/usr/local/a/1.txt
/usr/local/a/2.txt
/usr/local/a/3.txt
/usr/local/b/4.txt
/usr/local/b/3.txt
/usr/local/c/1.txt
/usr/local/c/7.txt
/usr/local/c/6.txt
/usr/local/c/12.txt
...
```

I want to delete all the files *.txt in subfolders except the last three files with the greatest modification date, but here I am in current directory

```
ls -tr *.txt | head -n-3 |xargs rm -f
```

I need to combine that with the code:

```
find /usr/local/**/* -type f
```

Should I use the maxdepth option?

Thanks for helping,
aola

Comment: *greatest modification date* means? Files modified last?

Comment: yes, files modified last

Comment: have a look at this, it deletes specific files in subdir http://superuser.com/questions/112078/delete-matching-files-in-all-subdirectories

Comment: find /usr/local -type f -name '*.txt' -printf '%T@|%p\n' | sort -r | cut -d '|' -f 2 | head -n-3 | xargs rm -f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added `maxdepth` options to find for one level, sorting files by last modification time, `tail` to ignore the oldest modified 3 files and `xargs` with `-r` to remove the files only if they are found.

```
 for folder in $(find /usr/local/ -type d)
 do     
     find $folder -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.txt" | xargs -r ls -1tr | tail -n+3 | xargs -r rm -f
 done
```

Run the above command once without `rm` to ensure that the previous commands pick the proper files for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got the solution: use `find` to get the files,`ls` to sort them by modification date and `tail` to omit three most recently modified ones:

```
find /usr/lib -type f | xargs ls -t | tail -n +4 | xargs rm
```

If you would like to remove only the files at a specified depth add `-mindepth 4 -maxdepth 4` to find parameters.

Comment: This only works if all args are fitting in one ls -t.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find's `-printf` option, to print the modification time in front of the file name and then sort and strip the date off. This avoids using ls at all.

```
find /usr/local -type f -name '*.txt' -printf '%T@|%p\n' | sort -r | cut -d '|' -f 2 | head -n-3 | xargs rm -f
```

The other Answers using `xargs ls -t` can lead to incorrect results, when there are more results than `xargs` can put in a single `ls -t` command.

Answer (score 0):

but for each subfolder, so when I have

```
/usr/local/a/1.txt
/usr/local/a/2.txt
/usr/local/a/3.txt
/usr/local/a/4.txt
/usr/local/b/4.txt
/usr/local/b/3.txt
/usr/local/c/1.txt
/usr/local/c/7.txt
/usr/local/c/6.txt
/usr/local/c/12.txt
```

I want to to use the code for each subfolder separately

```
head -n-3 |xargs rm -f
```

so I bet if I have it sorted by date then the files to delete:

```
/usr/local/a/4.txt
/usr/local/c/12.txt
```

I want to leave in any subfolder three newest files

Comment: Check out my updated answer to loop through all sub-folders in `/usr/local` to remove the files